# histograma de uma frase c++

Tags: c, string, histograma

fiz o seguinte programa para fazer o histograma de uma frase contando o numero de letras e consoantes existentes na mesma mas esta dando erro
pois estou tentando fazer com que ele imprima letras maiusculas e minusculas
acentuadas ou não..

```
#include <cstdio>

void histogram(char *);

int main()
{
    char str[50];

    printf("\n\tDigite uma frase: ");
    fgets(str,50,stdin);
    histogram(str);

}

void histogram(char *frase)
{
  int num=0, az=0;
  char alfabeto[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzçABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇ";

   for(num = 0; frase[num] != 0; num++)
    {
     if(frase[num] <= alfabeto[num])az++;
    }

   printf
    (
     "\n\n\tTemons %d letras \"%s\"\n\n"    
     , az, alfabeto[az]
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparação que tem no `for`:

```
if(frase[num] <= alfabeto[num])az++;
```

Não lhe contabiliza as letras corretamente, pois apenas está a comparar se a letra que tem é menor que a letra em que vai no alfabeto, e não se existe no alfabeto.

No entanto o erro que está a obter vem do ultimo `printf` em:

```
 printf
 (
 "\n\n\tTemons %d letras \"%s\"\n\n"    
 , az, alfabeto[az] //<-- aqui
 );
```

Pois imprime um `%s` com uma letra e não um endereço. É importante relembrar que um parametro do tipo `%s` espera um `char*` e não um `char`, que é o caso do `alfabeto[az]`. Pode passar o endereço da letra com `&alfabeto[az]`, mas ainda assim não vejo o objetivo de fazer isso.

Para contar as letras que fazem parte do alfabeto definido por si então precisa de um segundo `for` que percorre o `alfabeto` e verifica se a letra corrente coincide com a do `alfabeto`.

Sugiro então que faça assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void histogram(char *);

int main() {
    char str[50];

    printf("\n\tDigite uma frase: ");
    fgets(str,50,stdin);
    histogram(str);
    return 0;
}

void histogram(char *frase) {
    int num=0, num2=0, az=0;
    char alfabeto[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzçABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇ";

    for(num = 0; frase[num] != 0; num++) {
        for (num2 = 0; alfabeto[num2] != '\0'; ++num2){
            if (frase[num] == alfabeto[num2]){
                az++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n\tTemons %d letras\n\n", az);
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/fClxKJ)

Repare também que troquei o `include` para um apropriado de C em vez de C++.

---

**Edit:**

Se pretende saber a contagem de cada letra, é necessário contabilizar para um array, por cada tipo de letra. O próprio mostrar dos valores terá que ser feito com um `for` uma vez que terá um valor para cada letra que aparece.

Exemplo:

```
void histogram(char *frase) {
    int num=0, num2=0, az=0;
    char alfabeto[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzçABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇ";
    int contagens[256]; //array para as contagens das letras
    for (num= 0; num < 256; ++num){
        contagens[num]=0; //iniciar o array todo a zeros
    }

    for(num = 0; frase[num] != 0; num++) {
        for (num2 = 0; alfabeto[num2] != '\0'; ++num2){
            char letra = frase[num];
            if (letra == alfabeto[num2]){
                contagens[(int)letra]++; //contabilizar para a letra corrente
                az++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n\tTemons %d letras\n\n", az);
    for (num = 0; num < 256; ++num){
        if (contagens[num] > 0){ //mostrar apenas os que tem pelo menos 1 letra
            printf("\n%c: %d", (char)num, contagens[num]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/LLtMNw)

Para iniciar o array de contagens a zeros pode alternativamente utilizar a função [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/), fazendo `memset(contagens, 0, sizeof(contagens));`, no entanto implica incluir `string.h`.

Comment: ele esta mostrando a quantidade de letras existente na frase o que eu quero é que ele mostre por ex: dark777 tem 1 letra d, 1 letra a, 1 letra r, 1 letra k....

Comment: @dark777 Editei a resposta para contemplar essa lógica.